# Dividing with a remainder in PHP

Tags: php

I have a part in my code where I need to divide and have a remainder instead of a decimal answer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do what you are describing using the "%" (modulus) operator. The following code is an example of dividing with a remainder.

```
$remainder=$num % $divideby;
$number=explode('.',($num / $divideby));
$answer=$number[0];
echo $answer.' remainder '.$remainder;
```

Comment: Don’t use a string function on a float type. Better use `floor()`.

Comment: blindly using floor could fail on a negative result

Answer (score 24):

```
$quotient = intval($dividend / $divisor);
$remainder = $dividend % $divisor;
```

Using `intval` instead of `floor` will round the quotient towards zero, providing accurate results when the dividend is negative.

Comment: can yield wrong result if negative, e.g. if dividend=5 and divisor=2 you'd calculate 3 as the quotient rather than 2

Comment: Yes, I noticed that soon after posting and revised my reply to use `intval` rather than `floor`.

Comment: use `$remainder = fmod($dividend, $divisor)` when using non-integers

Answer (score 5):

A solution for positive and negative numbers:

```
$quotient = $dividend / $divison;
$integer = (int) ($quotient < 0 ? ceil($quotient) : floor($quotient));
$remainder = $dividend % $divisor;
```

Answer (score 4):

The [mathematical correct answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) is:

```
remainder = dividend % divisor;
quotient = (dividend - remainder) / divisor;
```

and the remainder verifies the condition `0 <= remainder < abs(divisor)`.

**Unfortunately, many programming languages (including PHP) don't handle the negative numbers correctly from the mathematical point of view.** They use [different rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to compute the value and the sign of the remainder. The code above does not produce the correct results in PHP.

If you need to work with negative numbers and get the mathematical correct results using PHP then you can use the following formulae:

```
$remainder = (($dividend % $divider) + abs($divider)) % abs($divider);
$quotient = ($dividend - $remainder) / $divider;
```

*They rely on the way PHP computes modulus with negative operands and they may not provide the correct result if they are ported to a different language.*

Here is a [script](https://3v4l.org/GGBti) that implements these formulae and checks the results against the values provided as example in the aforementioned mathematical correct answer.

Comment: To clarify, the first "code" snippet is a *mathematical* expression. `%` is the [mathematical modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). There, see *"In mathematics, the result of the modulo operation is an equivalence class, and any member of the class may be chosen as representative; however, the usual representative is the **least positive residue**, the smallest nonnegative integer which belongs to that class, i.e. the remainder of the Euclidean division."* Axiac is observing that PHP, for negative values, does not return *least positive residue*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to look it up, the % operator is called mod (or modulus).

Answer (score 0):

Use This Function Its an array
    Description
    array `gmp_div_qr ( resource $n , resource $d [, int $round ] )`

```
The function divides n by d .
```

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-div-qr.php

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop this approach because my numerator was a float value and modulus was rounding results.

Using Raffaello's approach offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218312/how-do-i-get-a-float-value-when-dividing-two-integers-php#21313533) for dividing floats and taking from Sam152's solution above came up with the following.

```
$a = 2.1;
$b = 8;
$fraction = $a / (float) $b;
$parts = explode('.', $fraction);                
$int = $parts[0];
$remainder = $score - ($int*$b) ;
```

Comment: Instead, could use [fmod function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php). `$quotient = $a / $b; $remainder = fmod($a, $b);`

Comment: fmod function can have strange behavior: `fmod(100.1, 0.1);` => 0.099999999999989 (should be 0)

Answer (score 0):

An example to show strings like 1 hour 6 minutes using floor() and modulus (%) if only minutes/seconds given:

```
$minutes=126;

if($minutes < 60) {
    $span= $minutes.' min.';
} else {
    $rem=$minutes % 60;
    $span=floor($minutes/60).' h. '. (($rem>0) ? $rem.' min.':'');
}

// echo 'Hello Jon Doe, we notify you that even will last for 2 h. 6 min.
echo 'Hello Jon Doe, we notify you that event will last for '.$span;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an old post, but for those who might be interested here is a very light package that could meet your needs: https://github.com/romainnorberg/residue (feedbacks are welcome)