# How do I get a float value when dividing two integers? (PHP)

Tags: php, floating, divide

Hi I am trying to divide two integers ex: 12/13 but I always get a whole integer 1 not a decimal number.

I tried type casting the values to float before hand with no success.

Basically all I want is a decimal result like: 0.923...

```
$x = 12;
$y = 13;
echo $value = $x / $y; //Would like to see 0.923 not 1
```

Comment: I get `0.92307692307692` when i run this

Comment: check your php.ini for enforced float decimal count or accuracy something like that can't remember what its called.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? `php -v` or `phpinfo();`

Comment: Is that your actual code, or did you try to simplify it before posting? Do you really get `1` with that extract?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under normal circumstances your code should return the floating value `0.923076`...

The reason you get a rounded integer might be because you have your `ini setting` for `"precision"` set to `0`, to fix this either edit your `php.ini` or use `ini_set("precision", 3);` in your code before the calculation.

Another way to workaround this is to use [BCmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php):

```
echo $value=bcdiv($a, $b, 3);
```

---

And yet another way without using any extension is to use a little math trick by multiplying the value you want to divide by `1000` to get `3 decimals`.
This way you'll divide `12000` by `13` and the whole part will be `923`, then since you multiplied by 1e3 insert a comma/dot before the last most 3 places.

```
function divideFloat($a, $b, $precision=3) {
    $a*=pow(10, $precision);
    $result=(int)($a / $b);
    if (strlen($result)==$precision) return '0.' . $result;
    else return preg_replace('/(\d{' . $precision . '})$/', '.\1', $result);
}
```

`echo divideFloat($a, $b); // 0.923`

Comment: No. With precision 0 we have `0.9`.http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision is not clear enough; longer explanation: PHP uses his own implementation of ((v)s)printf string parsing. The mode `%H` is used in the format string: it calls with the parameter `mode` set to `2` the function `zend_dtoa` in which documentation is indicated: `[mode] 2 ==> max(1,ndigits) significant digits. This gives a return value similar to that of ecvt, except that trailing zeros are suppressed.` (see: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_strtod.c#1457)) That's why `precision=1` == `precision=0`.

Answer (score 16):

```
echo $value = $x / (float) $y;
```

if you cast the variable `$y` as float the interpreter use the floating point division instead of integer division.

because it's default asumption to use integer division on two integer variables.

It was different if you used  `$y = 13.0` (a float variable as denominator):
The results is always a float number

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem so that future visitors can benefit from this question.

Answer (score 4):

All other answers are NOT RIGHT, because PHP's division will always return float values, as is stated clearly in official manual [PHP: Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) , except for cases when two operands are both integers which can be evenly divided.

In fact, the question is wrong: the code should produce 0.923..., as was expected from the questioner.

Sarcastically, the voted-down answer (came from @BulletProof47) is the only other one which is just NOT WRONG (but also meaningless). Who knows what he was thinking, but I bet everybody knows why it was voted down :D

In case who is interested, the underlying function which does division in php is `div_function`, located in `Zend/zend_operators.c`, shown below:

```
ZEND_API int div_function(zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
    zval op1_copy, op2_copy;
    int converted = 0;

    while (1) {
        switch (TYPE_PAIR(Z_TYPE_P(op1), Z_TYPE_P(op2))) {
            case TYPE_PAIR(IS_LONG, IS_LONG):
                if (Z_LVAL_P(op2) == 0) {
                    zend_error(E_WARNING, "Division by zero");
                    ZVAL_BOOL(result, 0);
                    return FAILURE;         /* division by zero */
                } else if (Z_LVAL_P(op2) == -1 && Z_LVAL_P(op1) == LONG_MIN) {
                    /* Prevent overflow error/crash */
                    ZVAL_DOUBLE(result, (double) LONG_MIN / -1);
                    return SUCCESS;
                }
                if (Z_LVAL_P(op1) % Z_LVAL_P(op2) == 0) { /* integer */
                    ZVAL_LONG(result, Z_LVAL_P(op1) / Z_LVAL_P(op2));
                } else {
                    ZVAL_DOUBLE(result, ((double) Z_LVAL_P(op1)) / Z_LVAL_P(op2));
                }
                return SUCCESS;
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use $value = (float)($x/$y); //Result will in float.

Cheers!

Comment: - The OP mentioned trying typecasting.