# PHP Division results automatically rounded up number

Tags: php

i have a simple division

```
$order = 14 / 10;   // 1
$order = 15 / 10;   // 2
```

result automatically convert into round figure

how can i get result like

```
$order = 14 / 10;   // 1.4
$order = 15 / 10;   // 1.5
```

here my actual code `$quantity`

```
if (($quantity > 0.99) && ($pro_Type== "BHRF")) {

    $pro_Id   = $pro_Id -10;
    $quantity = $quantity/10;

    for ($i=1; $i <11; $i++) { 

       $pro_Id = $pro_Id +10;

      $insert0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myorders1 (Product_Id,Quantity,Product_Type,Store_Id,Order_Date,Order_Time) 
                    VALUES ('$pro_Id','$quantity','$pro_Type','$store_Id','$o_Date','$o_Time')", $connection);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you put more code ? You use echo to show $order or other method ? no (int) cast ?

Comment: `$order = 1.0 * 14 / 10; // 1.4`

Comment: or try to cast $order before

Comment: Errr, for me: `$order = 14 / 10;  echo $order; //1.4` Did I missed something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218312/how-do-i-get-a-float-value-when-dividing-two-integers-php

Comment: @lolka_bolka please check my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless i'm drunk; `14/10` can't be 1 without any rounding involved

```
echo  14 / 10;    // 1.4 as expected
```

Most probably your database field, `Quantity`, is integer and doesnt store the fraction and you assume the real number came from division.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/233143)**

Comment: yes my bad , it means integer does not store number with decimal ?

Comment: Yes integers are real numbers. They don't store decimal values. For that you can have , among others, a DECIMAL type field.